# Twitter streaming api - how to read retweets

Tags: json, twitter, entities

Hey. I successfully installed Twitter Streaming API. I can read statuses but don't know exactly how to distinguish between tweets and retweets.

http://dev.twitter.com/pages/tweet_entities

So my questions are
- how do you know that a  is a tweet/retweet
- how can I get the list of user ids that have retweeted the original tweet

Thx.

Comment: I think, that if retweeted_status key exists then this is a retweet. Am I right? But why is retweeted key always false?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5710303/pulling-retweets-using-twitter-user-timeline-in-json-format/5775592#5775592

Answer (score 2):

`{ "retweeted": true }` is only the case if user logged into the streaming API did the retweeting.

See http://blog.programmableweb.com/2010/08/30/twitter-api-adds-retweet-count-and-more/

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for  particular RTs lets say from Jack and Paul. Jut track "RT @Jack" and "RT @Paul".

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON you get back from the API, you'll get data like this:

```
{
    "retweeted":false,
    "text":"Testing streaming api",
    "geo":{...}
}
```

Simply get the value of `retweeted` and you have your answer.

Comment: Although it seems that after Retweet one should get  "retweeted":false, but it's not like that even after Retweet I am not able to get the True Retweet Status in resoponse.I think there is some problem with the response.I had already developed the Twitter App for iphone.Even I am also looking for the same ....

Comment: Also, I believe this would detect whether the actual tweet being displayed *has been* retweeted.  It wouldn't detect whether it is a retweet itself.