# Pulling Retweets using Twitter user_timeline in JSON format

Tags: twitter

I'm currently using the script..

```
http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=1
```

.. to pull the most recent Tweet for a number of users to display on my website. However, I've ran into the problem that the JSON format doesn't display Retweets. I've read from [this link](http://groups.google.com/group/twitter-development-talk/browse_thread/thread/8ad98cf854fb3b9f?pli=1) that you must use "retweeted_by_me" to also display Retweets by I'm not quite sure how I would merge that with my current script.

Answer (score 8):

> **EDIT** : As of Twitter API **Version 1.1**, use the following format. (Needs Authenticaton)
>
> https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nikhilkuruvilla&include_rts=true
>
> The updated documentation can be found here
>
> https://dev.twitter.com/docs/api/1.1/get/statuses/user_timeline

**[UPDATE]** The following methods apply to Twitter API **Version 1** and is **Deprecated** now.

Use the new twitter API and add `include_rts=true` Eg: http://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/user_timeline.json?screen_name=nikhilkuruvilla&include_rts=true

Full documentation can be found here : http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline

Comment: This is the correct answer. However, as of 2012-10-05, Twitter seems to be ignoring the "include_rts" param.

Answer (score 0):

If you read the [GET statuses/user_timeline](http://dev.twitter.com/doc/get/statuses/user_timeline) documentation you fill find that by adding a parameter of `include_rts` set to `true` it will include retweets.

Comment: Hmm.. I failed to include that I did try http://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline/username.json?callback=twitterCallback2&count=2&include_rts=true and still did not display any retweeted Tweets.

Comment: You need to use the documented full API url of `https://api.twitter.com/1/statuses/...`

Comment: That's what the documentation says, but I'm not convinced it works. Native retweets (using Twitter.com) still don't appear in the results with include_rts=true as a GET parameter. That may actually be an API bug.

Comment: Yes. There appears to be a bug in the API. It does not seem to be working for me either.

Answer (score 0):

Change `response mode` to [rss](https://twitter.com/statuses/user_timeline.rss). This will resolve the issue. It might require change in the display code depending on your scripting language though.